# How to get status of _delete_by_query api in elasticsearch using scala

Tags: scala, elasticsearch

I am doing an HTTP post to elasticsearch in scala.

```
 Http(s"http://$elkIp:5051/$indexName/_delete_by_query")
          .postData(s"""{   "query": { "terms": { "zip_id.keyword": [$zipIds]}}}""")
          .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
          .header("Charset", "UTF-8")
          .options(HttpOptions.followRedirects(true)).asString
```

This post query returns.

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException

But the task gets queued up in elasticsearch which I verified using **_tasks** API.

I want to check the status of the same task in scala code and want to return the response when it is completed.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to add [`?wait_for_completion=false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query-task-api) to your request and you'll get the `<task_id>` in the response immediately.

You can then regularly check the task status by hitting `/_tasks/<task_id>`. As soon as `completed: true` returns, then you know the task has finished executing.

You need to also make sure to delete `.tasks/task/<task_id>` when your job is done otherwise it will stay in the task index.

Comment: I tried wirh Http(s"http://$elkIp:5051/$indexName/_delete_by_query?wait_for_completion=true") but still I got java.net.SocketTimeoutException.. It returns some response in case of NO or FEW documents found but timeout if bulk entries available

Comment: Woops, sorry my bad, my head thought `false` but I typed `true`... Fixed, sorry about that

Comment: Great it helped..got task_id but _tasks/<task_id> is still returning the JSON even though the task is complete

Comment: Are you sure it's complete? The pattern is that as long as it runs, it'll show up in `_tasks/<id>` and when done it shows up in `.tasks/task/<id>`

Comment: yes, it's complete. I checked in _tasks there is no delete task running

Comment: True, `_tasks/<id>` will check the `.tasks` index... So I've edited my answer a bit

Comment: Yes, I see that...Thanks. I also figured out a way to add the timeout .option(HttpOptions.connTimeout(100000)).option(HttpOptions.readTimeout(500000)) and it helped as well. By the way, do you have any idea why deletion is performing very slow for approx half a million documents?

Comment: Adding a timeout only helps if you know the task will end before that duration. If you don't, you should simply regularly check the task in a loop instead of hanging.

Comment: Anything else needed in this context?

Comment: No thanks, by any chance , do you have any idea why deletion is performing very slow for approx half a million documents?

Comment: Can you define "very slow"?

Comment: Delete by query will scroll over your index and delete data in batches of 100 records. What could help speed up the process is 1) to increase that batch size (your mileage may vary, try different sizes) and 2) to [slice your request](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query-slice)... So adding these parameters should help: `...&scroll_size=5000&slices=auto`