# Document Deletion in Elastic Search taking time

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I am using Spark with Scala to delete documents in Elastic Search but for deleting 250000 documents from one index below code is taking more than 20 minutes..
Any suggestion is highly appreciated

Code snippet is as below

```
val queryjson = s"""{"query":{"bool": {"must": {"match": {"zip_id": "$id"}}}}}"""

import scala.sys.process._

val deletecmd = List("curl", "-X", "POST","${conf.esNode}:5051/$indexName/_delete_by_query?routing=1&pretty", "-H","Content-Type: application/json", s"-d $queryjson")

val delqueryres = deletecmd.!!
print(delqueryres)
```

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59169952/4604579

Comment: @Val your answer helps to run an async deletion but doesn't improve performance.

Comment: @Rakesh can you share a bit more details about your index and why you expect a faster response ?

Comment: @baitmbarek We need to manage elk storage and need to delete quite lot of documents from indexes so want to make it quick..Below are my index settings{"spark_rules" : {
"settings" : {
"index" : {
"mapping" : {
"total_fields" : {
"limit" : "999999999999999999"
}
},
"number_of_shards" : "1",
"provided_name" : "spark_rules",
"max_result_window" : "1000000000",
"creation_date" : "1570264610206",
"number_of_replicas" : "1",
"uuid" : "FZbvxh6ASYivFhoC2mNRBA",
"version" : {
"created" : "7030299"
}
      }
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the refresh_interval to -1 to speedup your deletes. It avoids segment merges so I think it may help you.

See documentation link here : 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#bulk