# Why update_by_query returning "socket hang up" error when trying to update large number of documents?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am trying to add/update one field in all documents of an index using minimal queries but I am getting errors: **socket hang up** and then **version conflicts**. 
Referring to this [update_by_query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931757/how-to-update-multiple-documents-that-match-a-query-in-elasticsearch), I tried a similar query for my use case i.e

```
esClient.updateByQuery({
  index: "test_index",
  type: "_doc",
  body: {
    query: {
      match_all: {}
    },
    script: {
      lang: "painless",
      source: `ctx._source.name=params.name;`,
      params: { name: "raghu" }
    }
  }
});
```

After some more research, I added this `conflicts: "proceed"` option after which **version conflict** does not arrive but I am still getting **socket hang up** error.

================================================================================================

Though I can solve this using the following solution and it is working fine:

```
const limit = 10000;
//Iterating infinitely
while (true) {
  //adding required field for every batch if it doeas not exist
  const result = await esClient.updateByQuery({
    index: "test_index",
    type: "_doc",
    body: {
      query: {
        bool: {
          must_not: {
            exists: {
              field: "name"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      script: {
        lang: "painless",
        source: "ctx._source.name=params.name;",
        params: { name: "raghu" }
      }
    },
    size: limit,
    conflicts: "proceed"
  });
  const { updated } = result;
  //stop once updated result length is less than limit
  if (updated < limit) {
    //Done
    return result;
  }
}
```

I am using **Elastic Search v6.3.0 and NodeJs v10+**.

Can anyone explain why am I getting that error in the first case?

Comment: Your update is taking time so you should probably use `wait_for_completion: false` as well in roder to let the whole thing run in the background. See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59169952/4604579

Comment: Thanks, @Val Will check this and get back soon, According to you what would be a better approach for this first one or second?

Comment: If your index is continuously updated and you want to update it by query, then you  need to add `conflicts: proceed`. Then if your update takes time, then you need to also specify `wait_for_completion: false` and regularly check the update task in the background if you don't want to see those socket hang ups